# activerecord -- query many to many table for records from one of the tables (rather than just rows from the join table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I spent a lot of time today trying to figure out how to query a many to many table for records from one of the tables it belongs to.

If I have a members table that joins users and events, what kind of query would find all of the users attending a given event, or all of the events that a given user is attending?

I ultimately came across something like this (which works):

```
 User.joins(:members).where("members.event_id = ?", @event.id)
```

But can this kind of query be done without the SQL syntax? Something like:

```
Member.where(user: @user).first.events
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access user's events and event's users like this:

```
@event.users
@user.events
```

if you define The has_many :through association
(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members
  has_many :events, through: :members
end

class Member < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members
  has_many :users, through: :members
end
```